# Can i read a file from SmsManager

Tags: android

I copy+paste a `*.txt` file into the folder `/frameworks/opt/telephony/src/java/android/telephony`. Now I want to read it from `SmsManager`, but when I run the `"emulator + adb logcat"` it show me that it cant find the file.

Both files `SmsManager.java` and `textfile.txt` are in the same folder.

My code inside `SmsManager` is:

```
try {

      FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
      // Get the object of DataInputStream
      DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));           
          String line;

          // read every line of the file into the line-variable, on line at the time
          while (( line = br.readLine()) != null) {
              Log.i(TAG, line+"@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
          }



         in.close();
      } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
          Log.i(TAG, "File didnt found");
      } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
          Log.i(TAG, "File didnt found");
      }
```

What is wrong, or where must I save the file to find it?

Comment: You're trying to modify the Android source code? Why?

Comment: You will have to modify make files to include txt file inside Android. You cannot just drop the text file in any folder. When you modify make file, you can give where it can be put. It will usually be in /system/ which you need to open in your file

Comment: Which make files i must modify? I am new in android :)

Comment: check my answer. device.mk is the easiest to change, but i guess you can add it in any makefile which compiles

Answer (score 0):

You will have to modify device.mk like below to copy from your source code to Android file system

```
PRODUCT_COPY_FILES := frameworks/abc.txt:system/abc.txt
```

In your code you will have to access `/system/abc.txt`

Comment: so i must put my txt file into folder frameworks/ and then modify the device.mk with your proposal above. Am i right? sorry for all this but i am new in android.

Comment: yeah. But you will have to change the appropriate device.mk. Find any Android.mk that already uses PRODUCT_COPY_FILES and you can add your copy below it

Comment: I have modified the device.mk whick is in this folder:android/build/target/board/generic is it the right?

How can i know whick is the right device.mk?

Comment: as soon as you build you can check if it is copied in out/target/product/generic/system/

Comment: Yes it is copied, so now to read it i must write this sentence?

FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("/system/textfile.txt");

Comment: Thank you a lot. I have three more questions if you can.

1)Because i cant chat yet would you like to send me your email for future questions?


2)How can i add a application in the android source code?

3)this app will create a file that i want SmsManager to read it.How can i do this?

Thank you again.

Comment: leave your mail id here, i will mail you my id. 2. You can add the project to packages/apps/ change the Android.mk and add it to device.mk. It is quite complicated to write everything here, but you can refer the calculator app's Android.mk . 3. Reading from SmsManager should be possible but i really dont know how big is your data all such stuff